# Crystal Report and LINQ

Tags: linq, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report for creating a report. I have two tables, `Driver_Specifications` and `WatchRow`.

Primary key of `WatchRow` is foreign key of `Driver_Specifications`. I set some field in my report file to show the data of `Driver_Specifications` and I want to show a specific field of `WatchRow` instead of the foreign key of `Driver_Specifications`. What is the query of LINQ for this problem?

This is what I have so far:

```
var q = (from d in taxi_AgencyDataSet.Driver_Specifications
    orderby d.First_Name, d.ID_Driver
    select new {
        d.First_Name,
        d.Last_Name,
        d.Car_Name,
        d.Car_Color,
        d.WatchRow.Watch_Name,
        d.ID_Watch
    }).ToList();
```

I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: Why don't you post the names of your tables, fields and keys.  It's going to be hard to compose a linq query without them.

Comment: I have fixed the question based on information from comments to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `null` when accessing `d.WatchRow` to avoid throwing a `NullReferenceException`:

```
var q = (from d in taxi_AgencyDataSet.Driver_Specifications
         orderby d.First_Name, d.ID_Driver
         select new
         {
             d.First_Name,
             d.Last_Name,
             d.Car_Name,
             d.Car_Color,
             Watch_Name = d.WatchRow == null ? "None" : d.WatchRow.Watch_Name,
             d.ID_Watch
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah that's right , I write exactly like this , but I set some field for table1 in report file and set a field from table2 for set of specefic field like your example( Baz field ) but a error apear .
I dont know what shoul I do!!

Comment: @user356760: What is the error? If you could include your code in the question, and the error message too, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: This is a error that appear :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
and this is the code :
 var q =(from d in taxi_AgencyDataSet.Driver_Specifications
orderby d.First_Name, d.ID_Driver
                     select new
                     {
                         d.First_Name,
                         d.Last_Name,
                         d.Car_Name,
                         d.Car_Color,
                         d.WatchRow.Watch_Name,
                         d.ID_Watch
                     }).ToList();

Driver_Specifications is table1 and Whatch is table2

Comment: @danialtehrani: I mean refresh the page so that you can see that I have changed my answer. I have also added the extra information from your comment to the question. You should put this information into the question in the first place in future, please.

Comment: Yeah, I use your code but it dont let me compile it and I have this error :

Error 1 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access. F:\Ali\C#\Taxi Servis\Taxi Servis\ReportFrm.cs 209 14 Taxi Servis

Comment: @danialtehrani: Sorry there was an error in my code (I haven't tested it). I think it should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you, yeah it works .but now No data appear in my CrystalReportViewer control when I run the programm.